# LinearLayout change size

Tags: android, layout, resize, android-linearlayout

I have the next xml:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:src="@drawable/image_back" />

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutNames"
android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
android:layout_weight = "fill_parent"
android:layout_alignTop = "@+id/image_back"
android:layout_marginTop = "38dp" />

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutPoints
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:layout_weight = "wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom = "@+id/image_back"
android:layout_below = "@+id/linearLayoutNames" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my programatically code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutPoints = (LinearLayout)  findViewRoot(R.id.linearLayoutPoints);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayoutPoints.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = 200;
layoutParams.height = 300;
linearLayoutPoints.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

I want to resize the linearLayoutPoints but when Y try, nothing happens! Only resize it if I resize de imageView1 but i dont want that.
Dont know why.

help

Comment: Why are you using RelativeLayout.LayoutParams instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams?

Comment: because the parnt of my linearLayout is a relative layout

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this:

```
layoutParms.setMargin(0, 0, 0, (layoutParms.height -200));
```

This could work, because you layout is strained between the image and antoher layout.

Comment: Sorry i write wriong here! My mistake, i will edit my question

Comment: How do you know that the size of the layout does not change? There are no elements in the layout.

Comment: Another solution could be to remove the rule alignBottom in the code.

Comment: Try layoutParms.removeRule(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParms.ALIGN_BOTTOM);

Comment: i Will try removing rule. The layout has two more relative layouts. Have a backgroun color and thats how i can see if resize it or not

Comment: My min API is 14 and i need 17 min. Cant remove

Comment: Try it with the 17 api to isolate the problem

Comment: You can also try to get your current size and subtract the size you want to get. Then add the solution as margin bottom.